# what is the best way to use dates with java swing

Tags: java, swing, date

what i want to do is having like the java script popup date chooser in my application. i am using java swing and would like to avoid any input mistakes by the user. specifying a format is easy to implement but not user friendly for the user.
what are your suggestion ? any libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a date picker, like [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) or [JDatePicker](http://www.jdatepicker.org/).  Since users can't type raw date strings, you don't have to worry about their mistakes.

Edit: drhorrible is right.  I've fixed the link now.

Comment: I may be crazy, but I don't think your JCalendar link points to JCalendar...(is this it? http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html)

Comment: The link for JDatePicker above is incorrect, follow the following link http://jdatepicker.org

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of date picker libraries for Swing.

I have used the JXDatePicker from [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/) and [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

There was a commercial product called JDatePicker (I see this domain is now parked), the open source project which I started in 2004 with the same name has no relation to it. I not 100% sure who had the name first, but it seems like the former is no longer available.

You can find the open source [JDatePicker](http://jdatepicker.org) on [GitHub](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker) or SourceForge. The open source project will stay active as long as someone will need it.